# programa que calcula el factorial de numero

Tags: php

Estoy intentando hacer un programa que calcule el factorial de un número.

Lo hice con un while y si me funciono pero lo intento con un do while pero no me arroja ningun resultado

este es con while

```
<?php
$num=5;
$actorial=1;
$w=$num - 1;

while($w>=1){
    echo $actorial ."x". $w. "=";

    $actorial=$actorial * $w;
    echo $w--;

}
echo $actorial;

?>
```

arroja esto:

> 1x4=44x3=312x2=224x1=124

con do while

```
<?php
$w=$num-1;
$num=5;
$actorial=1;
do{

    echo $actorial ."x". $w. "=";
   $actorial=$actorial * $w;
   echo $w--;
   echo $actorial;


}while($w>=1);

?>
```

Comment: Bien, me fijo en las diferencias entre los 2 códigos y me doy cuenta de que en el código del Do While declaras antes $w que $num y en $w estas usando $num, prueba de poner bien las declaraciones de las variables a ver si es por eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La variable no existía cuando intentabas acceder a ella. Por otro lado he quitado `$w--` para que no salga por pantalla, ya que lo hacía algo lioso.

Aquí está corregido y funcionando:

```
$num=5;
$w=$num-1;
$actorial=1;
do{

   echo $actorial ."x". $w. "=";
   $actorial=$actorial * $w;
   $w--;
   echo $actorial;
   echo "  ";


}while($w>=1);
```

Comment: Hola Flowen, en que se diferencia tu respuesta de la de  Danielpmsv?

Comment: En que explico la razón por la que el orden de las variables le afecta en su caso. Y que el código está completo y listo para funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es el orden de declaración de las variables el código  debería ser:

```
<?php
$num=5;
$w=$num-1;
$actorial=1;
do{
...
```