# Error al mostrar valores en un bucle

Tags: php

Ando haciendo un programa que me haga números sucesivos del 10 al 1 pares, impares y múltiplos de cinco, pero no me arroja nada  y no entiendo cómo hace que el resultado se vea hacia abajo de forma de columnas:

```
10    2      3       1
9     4      5       5
8     6             10
7     8      11     15
```

Éste es el código:

```
<?php
$sucesivo=11-$i;
$pares=$i * 2;
$impares=$i * 2 - 1;
$quintos=$i * 5 -5;

for($i=1; $i<=10; $i++){

  echo $sucesivo,$pares,$impares,$quintos;

}

?>
```

Comment: No te saca nada por pantalla, porque las variables que imprimes no existen en tu código (o al menos en el que has copiado aquí)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionado.

`$i` no existe cuando estás usándolo en la primera línea de tu código.

```
<?php
$i=1;
$sucesivo=11-$i;
$pares=$i * 2;
$impares=$i * 2 - 1;
$quintos=$i * 5 -5;

for($i; $i<=10; $i++){

  echo $sucesivo,$pares,$impares,$quintos;

}

?>
```

De hecho, te pasó lo mismo en una pregunta que te resolví ayer: [Link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/107084/programa-que-calcula-el-factorial-de-numero)

Intenta entender la solución y buscar por tí mismo el error antes de preguntar cada ejercicio que tengas que realizar en este foro.

Comment: La salida al código que pones es: 10210102101021010210102101021010210102101021010210
 Para mi lo interesante sería ver como se distribuye en columnas como en la pregunta original, y lo digo porque eso de primeras no se me ocurre como hacerlo de forma sencilla...

Comment: El código que saca lo has programado tu, yo ya te he solucionado el problema por el que no obtenias nada por pantalla (No tener la variable iniciada).

Comment: si gracias solo que me arroja un solo resultado lo que no entendi ahi me arrojo esto 10210102101021010210102101021010210102101021010210 antes me habia rrojado bien los resultados pero ocupo que se vea de arriba hacia abajo es lo que no se como se hace pares impares multiplos de 5 pero como de forma de tabla hacia abajo

Comment: Utiliza saltos de línea [Saltos de línea PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994769/how-to-add-a-line-break-within-echo-in-php)