# tabla de numeros

Tags: php

Tengo un programa que imprime números pares impares y múltiplos de quintos pero ocupo que el resultado se mire así en columnas hacia abajo me imprime lineal

```
10     2        3        1
9      4        5        5
8      8        7       10
7     10        9       15
```

Éste es el código

```
<?php

$i=1;
$sucesivo=11-$i;
$pares=$i * 2;
$impares=$i * 2 - 1;
$quintos=$i * 5 -5;

while($i<=10){

    echo $i++,$sucesivo,$pares,$impares,$quintos;
}


?>
```

Me arroja esto:

```
1102102102103102104102105102106102107102108102109102101010210
```

Comment: Esto ya te lo he solucionado en la pregunta anterior, y aún así abres otra pregunta. Si para cada paso que quieres realizar haces una pregunta nueva en el foro, no vas a conseguir aprender por tí mismo. Esto es tan sencillo como buscar en google `salto de linea php`, o mirar el link que [te he facilitado antes...](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/107394/error-al-mostrar-valores-en-un-bucle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que imprimir el salto de línea al final del `echo`:

```
echo $i++,$sucesivo,$pares,$impares,$quintos,"\n";
```

Si quieres ponerle espacios entre cada parámetro entonces le puedes añadir una tabulación:

```
echo $i++,"\t",$sucesivo,"\t",$pares,"\t",$impares,"\t",$quintos,"\n";
```